# Access to DataFrame stored in parent class from child

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently trying to implement some inheritance in my Python project. I m trying to save some treatment of DataFrame done in parent class an pass the clean DataFrame to the child class. But I'm not able to access to the parent DataFrame from the child class

```
import pandas as pd


class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self, Prop1, Prop2):
        self._Prop1 = Prop1
        self._Prop2 = Prop2

    def main(self):
        self.Parent_Method()
        X = Child()
        X.Child_Method()

    def Parent_Method(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame([self._Prop1, self._Prop2])


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Child_Method(self):
        print(self.df)
```

buy calling the main() method of the Parent Class I'm getting an error saying that Child object has no attribute 'df'

```
from OOP import Parent
x = Parent(10, 20)
x.main()
```

`AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'df'`

Comment: With the way this is currently setup, not even `Parent`  has a `df` attribute until `Parent_Method` is called.

Comment: @HenryEcker this looks to me like a simplified version of a much more complex problem. this is a great example of how one should ask a question on this platform. I had the same problem myself when I wanted my data augmentation object to use other data points from my PyTorch dataset which contained that object. In other words, I wanted the item to access other items in the container, which this person has asked about simply and clearly. kudos to OP

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by giving the child a pointer to the parent.

```
class Parent(object):
    
    def __init__(self, Prop1, Prop2):
        
        self._Prop1 = Prop1
        self._Prop2 = Prop2
        
    def main(self):
      
        self.Parent_Method()
        X = Child(self)
        X.Child_Method()


    def Parent_Method(self):    
        
        self.df = pd.DataFrame([self._Prop1, self._Prop2])
        
        
class Child(Parent):
    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        pass
    
    def Child_Method(self): 
        print(self.parent.df)
```

Here's an example of what I get when I run this code.
It's not a pandas DataFrame, but the concept is the same.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @yan ziselman. It works for me !

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your `df` in the `init` before using it:

```
        def __init__(self,df):
          self.df=df
```