# Accessing a DataFrame inside of a class

Tags: python, dataframe, class

I have created a DataFrame inside of a class but I am having trouble using it outside of the class or even calling it. How would I do that? I just want to print the DataFrame outside of the class.

```
class Youpi(Baseball, Soccer): 
    def __init__(self): 
        Baseball.__init__(self, self)
        self.Random_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Hot-Dogs"])
        
        
    def Attendance(self, hot_dogs):
        dictionary = {"Hot-Dogs":5}
        self.Random_df = self.Random_df.append(dictionary, ignore_index=True)
        return self.Random_df

Desired output:

// instruction to print the dataframe here

Output:

Hot-Dogs
  5
```

Comment: Did you see this? It could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67587301/access-to-dataframe-stored-in-parent-class-from-child

Answer (score 0):

I would try print(dictionary.Attendance)